# Is there a way of retrieving coordinates from pseudotime plots in Monocle?

Tags: r, coordinates

I'd like to do some further analysis on some `pseudotime` plots created using the package Monocle from `Bioconductor`.

To do this, I would like to retrieve the coordinates. I know that it's possible to do this using the `gatepoints` package for scatter plots, but would this work for `pseudotime` plots?

The plotted data must be in matrix or `dataframe` format for this to work. e.g. see code below. I'm just not sure what the in-built plotting format is for `pseudotime` plots using Monocle.

```
a <- data.frame(pseudotime = c (1:11), gene_expression = c(0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100))
plot(a)
selectedPoints<-fhs(a)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monocle uses ggplot2, so you can get the data from the plot object. For example:

```r
library("monocle")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

lung <- load_lung()
#> Removing 4 outliers
diff_test_res <- differentialGeneTest(lung)
ordering_genes <- row.names(subset(diff_test_res, qval < 0.01))
lung <- setOrderingFilter(lung, ordering_genes)
p <- plot_ordering_genes(lung)


coords <- data.frame(
  select(p$data, !!p$mapping$x),
  select(p$data, !!p$mapping$y)
)

p
#> Warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
```

[image]

```r
plot(log10(coords$mean_expression), log10(coords$dispersion_empirical))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really useful to know!

Comment: Hi Alan, do you know how I would find the coordinates of the best fit curve generated from the code that plots the expression vs pseudotime for individual markers? i.e. from the following function:
plot_genes_in_pseudotime(cds_subset, color_by = "Hours")

Comment: Ask this as a new question with some example code, please.

Comment: Many thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192188/y-coordinates-of-best-fit-curve-in-ggplot2

Comment: Hi Alan, do you have any time to help me with a new question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528103/plotting-all-genes-in-pseudotime-in-monocle