# Y Coordinates of Best Fit Curve in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have managed to generate pseudotime vs gene expression plots in Monocle for individual markers using the following code:

```r
library("monocle")

lung <- load_lung()
diff_test_res <- differentialGeneTest(
  lung,
  fullModelFormulaStr = "~genotype"
)

ordering_genes <- diff_test_res[diff_test_res$qval < 0.01, "gene_id"]
lung <- setOrderingFilter(lung, ordering_genes)
plot_ordering_genes(lung)
#> Warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
```

[image]

```r
lung <- reduceDimension(
  lung,
  max_components = 2,
  method = 'DDRTree'
)
lung <- orderCells(lung)
lung_expressed_genes <-  fData(lung)[fData(lung)$num_cells_expressed >= 5, "gene_id"]
lung_filtered <- lung[lung_expressed_genes, ]
my_genes <- rownames(lung_filtered)[1:3]
lung_subset <- lung_filtered[my_genes, ]

plot_genes_in_pseudotime(lung_subset, color_by = "genotype")
```

[image]
The "plot_genes_in_pseudotime" function on the final line generates a best fit curve of the plotted data. I was wondering if the y coordinates of this curve can somehow be obtained for say, every 0.01 units along the pseudotime axis? You can find the code and example plots here: http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle-release/docs/#trajectory-step-3-order-cells-along-the-trajectory

Comment: I couldn't run your code as you posted it. Can you check that what I've added is roughly representative? It generally helps a lot to post code that can be run directly including data as I've done here. I generally won't go out of my way to test code I can't run immediately.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Pseudotime and `"expectation"` values that comprise the curve in `plot$data` (monocle just plots Pseudotime against spline-smoothed mean expression for the specified genes).

You can then use `approxfun` to do 2d interpolation and evaluate a grid of points along the range of pseudotime.

**NOTE: I am not sure this is a sensible thing to do. Pseudotime is a fairly loose and wooly thing, and reading deeply into minute changes in pseudotime is likely to lead to pretty shaky conclusions.**

In any case, if you're interested in using this type of approach I would just read the code [on github](https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/monocle-release/blob/2c9def9/R/plotting.R#L674) as it should be fairly easy to reproduce the output.

```r
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library("monocle")

lung <- load_lung()
#> Removing 4 outliers
diff_test_res <- differentialGeneTest(
  lung,
  fullModelFormulaStr = "~genotype"
)

ordering_genes <- diff_test_res[diff_test_res$qval < 0.01, "gene_id"]
lung <- setOrderingFilter(lung, ordering_genes)
lung <- reduceDimension(
  lung,
  max_components = 2,
  method = 'DDRTree'
)
lung <- orderCells(lung)
lung_expressed_genes <-  fData(lung)[fData(lung)$num_cells_expressed >= 5, "gene_id"]
lung_filtered <- lung[as.character(lung_expressed_genes), ]
my_genes <- rownames(lung_filtered)[1:3]

## Use only 1 gene here. Otherwise the plot data will include multiple genes
lung_subset <- lung_filtered["ENSMUSG00000000031.9", ]

p <- plot_genes_in_pseudotime(lung_subset, color_by = "genotype")
df <- p$data
fun <- approxfun(df$Pseudotime, df$expectation)

s <- seq(min(df$Pseudotime), max(df$Pseudotime), by = 0.01)
plot(s, fun(s))
```

[image]