# Plotting all genes in pseudotime in Monocle

Tags: r, rna-seq

I would like to use code similar to the code just below that works for the lung dataset in the package Monocle:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library("monocle")
lung <- load_lung()
diff_test_res <- differentialGeneTest(
  lung,
  fullModelFormulaStr = "~genotype"
)
ordering_genes <- diff_test_res[diff_test_res$qval < 0.01, "gene_id"]
lung <- setOrderingFilter(lung, ordering_genes)
plot_ordering_genes(lung)
lung <- reduceDimension(
  lung,
  max_components = 2,
  method = 'DDRTree'
)
lung <- orderCells(lung)
p = plot_genes_in_pseudotime(lung)
df = p$data
df
```

I want to run the following for my own dataset, but the last line is taking too long. The diff_test_res line also takes approximately 5 minutes, but this is instant for the lung datset whose size is comparable to mine:

```
#Create CellDataSet object

cds <- newCellDataSet(expr_matrix.s4, phenoData = pd, featureData = fd, expressionFamily=negbinomial.size())  
cds <- estimateSizeFactors(cds)
cds <- estimateDispersions(cds)
cds <- detectGenes(cds, min_expr = 0.1)
expressed_genes <- row.names(subset(fData(cds), num_cells_expressed >= 10))

#Cluster

disp_table <- dispersionTable(cds)
unsup_clustering_genes <- subset(disp_table, mean_expression >= 0.1)
cds <- setOrderingFilter(cds, unsup_clustering_genes$gene_id)
cds <- reduceDimension(cds, max_components = 2, num_dim = 6,
                   reduction_method = 'tSNE', verbose = T)
cds <- clusterCells(cds, num_clusters = 4)

#Plot differentially expressed genes in pseudotime

cds_myo <- estimateDispersions(cds)
diff_test_res <- differentialGeneTest(cds_myo[expressed_genes,],fullModelFormulaStr = '~Cluster', cores = 10)
ordering_genes <- row.names (subset(diff_test_res, qval < 0.01))
cds_myo <- setOrderingFilter(cds_myo, ordering_genes)
plot_ordering_genes(cds_myo)
cds_myo <- reduceDimension(
  cds_myo,
  max_components = 2,
  method = 'DDRTree'
)
cds_myo <- orderCells(cds_myo)
p = plot_genes_in_pseudotime(cds_myo)
```

Does anyone familiar with Monocle know how I can speed it up?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would guess that you either have more expressed genes or more clusters, causing the differential test to be slower. If you then have more differentially expressed genes, it's likely that you're trying to plot a lot of genes, which may take a long time. You could try to be more stringent in your filtering of expressed genes or of differentially expressed genes. However it's hard to say without knowing what the data are like

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try that!